# Deleting an object from ViewModel that is displayed as a child of custom view

Tags: android, parent-child, viewmodel, android-custom-view

I have a Room local database that holds User objects. 
These user objects are fetched at my MainActivity `onCreare()` and are filling a local Arraylist that I hold -

```java
private UserViewModel userViewModel;
private ArrayList<User> usersList;
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    observeLiveData();

    initViewsAndListeners();
  }
private void observeLiveData() {
    userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);
    userViewModel.getAllUsers().observe(this, users -> {
      //update a new list of users
      usersList = (ArrayList) users;
      addCards(-1);
    });
  }
```

That arraylist is being iterated inside a loop, creating custom frame layout views as a child to another custom view that holds them all -

```java
private void initViewsAndListeners() {
    tinderStackLayout = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_tinder_stack_layout);
    mDeleteButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_delete_button);
    mPassButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_pass_button);
    mApproveButton = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_approve_button);
    mDeleteButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mApproveButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mPassButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    listener = new OnCardSwipedListener() {
      @Override
      public void send(Object object) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onNext(Integer integer) {


        if (integer == 1) {
          addCards(1);
        }

      }
    };
  }
private void addCards(int stackSizeToAdd) {
    TinderCardView tinderCardView;
    for (int i = index; index < i + (STACK_SIZE + stackSizeToAdd); index++) {
      if (index >= usersList.size()) {
        index = 0;
        i = 0;
        addCards(-1);
      }
      tinderCardView = new TinderCardView(this, listener);
      tinderCardView.bind(usersList.get(index));
      tinderStackLayout.addCard(tinderCardView);
    }
  }
```

The views are being displayed one on the top of the other as cards that are swipable left or right, Tinder style

So, my question is the followin - 
I have inside my ViewModel a delete function that takes a user and deletes it from my Room database.

What would be the correct user to delete? is it userList.get(0)? and if so, according to my code as I provided, how do I make the arraylist automatically update itself as the database is being observed with LiveData

Here is an image of my app MainActivty for demonstration purpose -

[image]

Comment: Sorry dude your addCards method if quite confusing. Do you want to delete the user when card is being swiped left?

Comment: @user3783123 yeah it is really confusing, I am currently re-building this method for simplicity reasons. What I want to achieve is deleting the card when a specific button is clicked first, later I will copy the logic to swippping.